# Symfony2.5 : Bad credentials when switching from php5.6 to php7.0 on production

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, php-7, ovh

after migrating from php5.6 to php7.0 on (dev and prod), i'm prevented to connect on my admin account although i can create a new one !
i get `"Bad credentials"`
My security.yml :

```
security:
    encoders:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext
        Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User: sha512
```

any idea please.

Comment: Try to only use :  `FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512`

Comment: yes i did, but it seems that the problem persist unless i create another account ! but those who already connected cant get in !

Comment: Have you the same problem when you create a new account ?

Comment: If you can connect with the new account then problem come from php version. Whatever i think that you have to delete and create all account. You can do it with datafixtures

Comment: yes i can create new ones, but how to use datafixtures in this case ?

Comment: **1**. Save your database  **2.** Install [AliceBubndle] (https://github.com/hautelook/AliceBundle#installation)  **3.** Config [user.yml] (https://github.com/adashbob/scolen/blob/master/src/Ecole/UserBundle/DataFixtures/ORM/Dev/users.yml) and [function to load fixture] (https://github.com/adashbob/scolen/blob/master/src/Ecole/UserBundle/DataFixtures/ORM/Dev/DataLoader.php).  **4.** Execute command `php bin/console h:d:f:l`

Comment: By default user's role is the default role in `security.yml` file. If you want to add role for exemple `ROLE_ADMIN` add `roles: [ROLE_ADMIN]` in your `user.yml` file

Comment: thanks i'm going to do it

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you have two encoders specified, try to comment the first one as you're loading user from database use

```
security:
    encoders:
        Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User: sha512
```